# contact form get blank in webmail

Tags: php, html, forms, contact-form

i just try make contact form style of html look good on my website but i am dont know how get it work with PHP cos it sent email to webmail get blank information so anyone can help me better PHP form. thanks

```
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="subjects" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
                </div>                        
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Send Now</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

this file is sendemail.php

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subjects = $_POST['subjects'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "admin@cybermediaclub.co.uk";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the subject its normal that you dont see anything. Cause it doesn't find the variable $subject :

```
$subjects = $_POST['subjects'];
...
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
```

And that I think breaks all and thats the reason you see nothing.

Solution :

```
mail($recipient, $subjects, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
```

Comment: still same problem getting blank information. so any chance new php script better then this?

Comment: If it doesnt work you should check if the $subjects and $message variables holds any datas. So put this :  echo $subjects." ".$message;

Comment: If it doesnt work take a look at this exemple ... http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php

Comment: still not working at all. i need new php script to make it work with webmail.

Comment: I just put a link to another exemple James.

Comment: i did try this website aswell still not working for me. so any chance make new php codes.

Comment: If that exemple doesnt work for you ... maybe its sendmail_path on your server that isnt well set

Comment: Create an info.php file with this content : <?php  phpinfo(); ?> , and execute it

Comment: Search on the returned page sendmail_path and share the result with us

Comment: It seems ok ... but I confirm that your original form doesnt work for me either

Comment: told you. so can you try make new PHP code for me to make sure it work.

Comment: This is the simplest send mail script I found which works on my server :  http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/sending-email-from-site/using-the-php-mail-function-to-send-emails

Comment: i try this as still not work. cos i use 2 files HTML landing page and one PHP for sendemail.php that all. its so impossible. i need PHP CODE!!!!

Comment: i try new php code as still getting blank information.

<?php
//start building the mail string
$msg  = "Name:    ".$_POST['name']."\n";
$msg  = "Subjects:    ".$_POST['subjects']."\n";
$msg .= "E-Mail:  ".$_POST['email']."\n";
$msg .= "Message: ".$_POST['message']."\n";
//set up the mail
$recipient = "admin@cybermediaclub.co.uk";
$subject = "Form Submission Results";
$mailheaders  = "From: My Web Site <admin@cybermediaclub.co.uk> \n";
$mailheaders .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST['email'];
//send the mail
mail($recipient, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);
?>

Comment: still not,, didn't get any many script work cos been research many site as mostly get blank message tho.

Comment: Thats weird man ... At least one script worked for me and your php infos seemed ok ... Do you have an skype ID to talk more cause its pretty interesting what's going on

Comment: Those not work for my server side of webmail. yes i do have Skype ID is webcodez

Answer (score 0):

```
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
```

This line here should be:

```
$formcontent="From:" .  $name . "\nMessage:" . $message;

And $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
```

Should be

```
$mailheader = "From:". $email . "\r\n";
```

Comment: This souldn't be a problem at all, unless he uses a very old version of PHP.

Comment: thank you, just made change and test as still getting blank email in webmail.